# How to elegantly caclulate probability distribution parameters for a particular random variable given some observed data?

Tags: probability, distribution, bayesian-networks

I am using **bnlearn** package and R to learn Bayesian Network structure and also fit it using Maximum Likelihood estimation(MLE). ***bn.fit*** uses MLE to learn[as i understand] a generalized probability distribution for all data. However, it is required to obtain probability distribution for a particular variables given observed (evidence) data from other variables.
There one straighforward answer is to sample required variable for given evidence variables and fit probability distribution from that data. I am new to **bnlearn** package and Bayes Nets and thinking of maybe there is more natural way of obtatining those probability distribution parameters?

Comment: (+1) Please elaborate on some points to make your question more clear: a) *generalized probability distribution for all data.*  b) *...for a particular variables given observed (evidence) data from other variables.* c) *...required variable for given evidence variables and fit ...*.